# Parse Cloud Code Increment Trouble

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am not familiar with Javascript or Cloud Code and only began using CC yesterday. This seems like an extremely simple task, but I am banging my head trying to figure this out.

When a 'Chat' object is saved to parse, I want to increment the 'numberOfMessages' (of type Number) field of a 'ChatRooms' object, where ChatRooms.objectId = Chat.RoomId

Easy. I've tried many many things, here is the latest which is straight from the Parse Docs.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Chat", function(request, response) {
                  query = new Parse.Query("ChatRooms");
                  query.get(request.object.get("roomId"), {
                            success: function(post) {
                            post.increment("numberOfMessages", 1);
                            post.save();
                            response.success();
                            },
                            error: function(error) {
                            console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
                            response.error();
                            }
                            });
                  });
```

In this example, there error is:

```
ReferenceError: response is not defined
at query.get.success (main.js:7:33)
at Parse.js:2:7706
at e (Parse.js:2:6486)
at Parse.js:2:5935
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:664)
at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:5886)
at e (Parse.js:2:6621)
at Parse.js:2:5935
at Array.forEach (native) (Code: 141, Version: 1.5.0)
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

And finally.. are there any good resources for learning Javascript as it relates to Parse Cloud Code? My search didn't turn up anything useful. Thanks!

Comment: Is the column ChatRooms.roomId a Pointer or a String?

Comment: Chat.roomId is a string containing a given ChatRooms.objectId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
request.object.get("roomId").id
```

with

```
request.object.get("roomId")
```

since `roomId` is a string rather than a Room object.

**Update**: Also, add `response.success()` to the success handler and `response.error()` to the error handler to let Parse.com know you're done.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already removed the .id in my trials and receive the same error: Error: success/error was not called (Code: 141, Version: 1.5.0)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get 'response is not defined'.

Comment: I got it working. I forgot to add function(response, request). Updated my post to show final working code. Thanks for the help.